# How do I open this game?

Tags: physical-media

I recently bought some shrink-wrapped bargain bin games. Most of them seem like normal reprints of games but one has an extremely strange case that I can't figure out. (Apologies for the potato quality photos)

[image: Pic1]

This seems to be a normal dvd-type case expect that there is an extra red piece of plastic that fits into the edge of the case and extends behind the disc, preventing me from removing the disc normally.

[image: Rear Shot]

I've already forced the case open somewhat to get this far, as the red piece does had teeth that fit into both edges of the case, holding it closed.

[image: Pic 3]
[image: Pic 4]

I'd like preserve the case, however, and not force the case anymore then I have to.

Some other things to note about the case:

- I believe it's a reprint imported from the UK
- There is some black material inset in the back of the red piece
- There seems to be a bit of metal in the "head" of the red plastic, where it holds both sides of the case together (note the shine coming from inside it in the third picture)

I'm honestly at a loss as to how this case works and how I can remove the red strip. **So how do I open my game?**

Comment: I'm sure I've had a case like this once, a long time ago. It looks like you could try pushing down on the red band on the right side of your second image, and while holding it down slide out the bar from the left. Really can't remember how I opened mine now - I may have just forced it in the end...

Comment: This is a device intended to prevent theft, if the shop you purchased it from doesn't have the facility to remove it then I don't think there's sn option that can preserve the case. Is it stopping you taking the disc out?

Comment: The strip is threaded through the back of the case (you can see it in pic 2) and is preventing the push-to-release button from working normally.

Comment: Thinking back - I may have watched a YouTube video of someone removing that plastic strip and just followed their instructions

Comment: Not the same one that I watched, but [here's a video of someone removing an identical strip from a DVD case](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8HY0aH8kAs). They seem to keep the case pretty much intact too, which is a bonus.

Comment: Ah that video is perfect! I didn't want to bend the disc too much, but that video gave me the confidence to try the method out. It took a bit of bending but I got the disc and the strip out, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common anti-theft tag that's used here in the UK.

[Here's a video of someone removing one with a butter knife](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8HY0aH8kAs)